# How to make custom libraries in Laravel - as in codeigniter

Tags: laravel, codeigniter

i'm used to write a lot in codeigniter, where i try to place all logic code inside libraries instead of controllers.

The idea is a controller calls a library that calls a model to get data. 
So whatever is happening inside a library, can be called from multiple controllers easily, without rewriting code.

Now i'm baby stepping to laravel  and i cannot find anything about custom libraries. I perfectly managed to call a model from a controller, but I want to have a controller calling a library and the library calling the model.

I'm not able to find libraries (not packages), do they exist in laravel ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel works with Services and Providers, you create your service and write a provider for it. [Laravel Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers)

Also you can have Services Directory which is served through Providers Directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. First create Libraries directory inside app, then just create simple classes inside Libraries with functions which will call the models. remember to write

   `namespace App\Libraries`

   in every library you create.
2. then in composer.json add this line `"App\\Libraries\\": "src"` as the result your composer.json will become something like this

   ```
    `"autoload":{
        "psr-4": {
         "App\\": "app/",
         "App\\Libraries\\": "src",

    },}`
   ```
3. simply in your controller instantiate the library you want and use it's functions.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very good and simple method. I am using this.

Answer (score 0):

You  mean using namespacing ?
if you mean that take look about this post , its explain how create package http://culttt.com/2013/06/24/creating-a-laravel-4-package/

Comment: I dont know for sure, i'm just trying to understand if making libraries is legit in laravel, or else where should i write my code logic.

Comment: Yes you can do it , first should add this into your composer.jason "autoload": {
  "classmap": [
    // --
    "app/lib"
  ]
}  then run composer dump-autoload then add  your  library to provider

Comment: More detail here : http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/

Comment: library is like creating repository in your  case . When you finish you can call your library anywhere and better than calling from anywhere repository pattern give you a strong architecture to maintain your app